Improper Integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \log^2(t) t^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{-t} \, d t$
The integral I'm trying to solve is
\begin{align*}
    I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \log^2(t) t^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{-t} \, d t.
\end{align*}
Using Frullani's integral, note that
\begin{align*}
    \log(t) = - \, \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-xt}-e^{-x}}{x} \, d x.
\end{align*}
Hence,
\begin{align*}
    I &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \log^2(t) t^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{-t} \, d t\\
    &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \left[ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-xt}-e^{-x}}{x} \, d x \right] \left[ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-yt}-e^{-y}}{y} \, d y \right] t^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{-t} \, d t\\
    &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{y} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} \left[ \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{-t} \left(e^{-xt}-e^{-x}\right) \left(e^{-yt}-e^{-y}\right) \, d t \right] \, d x \, d y\\
    &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{y} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} \left[ \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{-t(1+x+y)} \, d t - \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{-t(1+x)-y} \, d t \right.\\
    &\qquad \left. - \, \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{-t(1+y)-x} \, d t + \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{-x-y-t} \, d t \right] \, d x \, d y\\
    &= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{y} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} \left[ \frac{1}{(1+x+y)^{3/2}} - \frac{e^{-y}}{(1+x)^{3/2}} - \frac{e^{-x}}{(1+y)^{3/2}} + e^{-x-y} \right] \, d x \, d y.
\end{align*}
Integrating by parts with $\ d v=\frac{1}{x} \, d x$, we have
\begin{align*}
    I &= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{y} \left\{ \left[ \log(x) \left( \frac{1}{(1+x+y)^{3/2}} - \frac{e^{-y}}{(1+x)^{3/2}} - \frac{e^{-x}}{(1+y)^{3/2}} + e^{-x-y} \right) \right]_{x=0}^{x=\infty} \right.\\
    &\qquad \left. - \, \int_{0}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{3e^{-y} \log(x)}{2(1+x)^{5/2}} + \frac{e^{-x} \log(x)}{(1+y)^{3/2}} - \frac{3\log(x)}{2(1+x+y)^{5/2}} - e^{-x-y} \log(x) \right] \, d x \right\} \, d y\\
    &= - \, \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{y} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{3e^{-y} \log(x)}{2(1+x)^{5/2}} + \frac{e^{-x} \log(x)}{(1+y)^{3/2}} - \frac{3\log(x)}{2(1+x+y)^{5/2}} - e^{-x-y} \log(x) \right] \, d x \, d y\\
    &= - \, \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{y} \left\{ \frac{3e^{-y}}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(x)}{(1+x)^{5/2}} - \frac{1}{(1+y)^{3/2}} \left[ - \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \log(x) \, d x \right] \right.\\
    &\qquad \left. - \, \frac{3}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(x)}{(1+x+y)^{5/2}} \, d x + e^{-y} \left[ - \, \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} \log(x) \, d x \right] \right\} \, d y\\
    &= - \, \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{y} \left\{ 2e^{-y} [\log(2)-1] - \frac{1}{(1+y)^{3/2}} \gamma - \frac{\log(y+1)}{(y+1)^{3/2}} - \frac{2[\log(2)-1]}{(y+1)^{3/2}} + e^{-y} \gamma \right\} \, d y.
\end{align*}
Integrating by parts once again with $\ d v=\frac{1}{y} \, d y$, we have
\begin{align}
    \nonumber I &= - \, \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \left\{ \left[ \log(y) \left( 2e^{-y} [\log(2)-1] - \frac{1}{(1+y)^{3/2}} \gamma - \frac{\log(y+1)}{(y+1)^{3/2}} \right. \right. \right.\\
    \nonumber &\qquad \left. \left. \left. - \, \frac{2[\log(2)-1]}{(y+1)^{3/2}} + e^{-y} \gamma \right) \right]_{0}^{\infty} - \int_{0}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{3\log(y)}{2(1+y)^{5/2}} + \frac{3[\log(2)-1] \log(y)}{(y+1)^{5/2}} \right. \right.\\
    \nonumber &\qquad \left. \left. - \, 2e^{-y} \log(y) [\log(2)-1] - \frac{\log(y)}{(y+1)^{5/2}} + \frac{3 \log(y+1) \log(y)}{2(y+1)^{5/2}} - e^{-y} \log(y) \gamma \right] \, d y \right\}\\
    &= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{3\log(y)}{2(1+y)^{5/2}} + \frac{3[\log(2)-1] \log(y)}{(y+1)^{5/2}} - 2e^{-y} \log(y) [\log(2)-1] \right. \\
    \nonumber &\qquad \left. - \, \frac{\log(y)}{(y+1)^{5/2}} + \frac{3 \log(y+1) \log(y)}{2(y+1)^{5/2}} - e^{-y} \log(y) \gamma \right] \, d y \\
    \nonumber &= \ldots\\
    \nonumber &= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \left[4\log^2(2) + (4\gamma-8)\log(2) + \frac{\pi^2}{2} + \gamma^2 - 4\gamma\right].
\end{align}
I could almost solve the integral in the third-to-last line. However, in the said integral, I haven't found the answer to
\begin{align*}
    \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{3 \log(y+1) \log(y)}{2(y+1)^{5/2}} \, d y.
\end{align*}
Firstly, I have no idea how to solve this particular integral. Secondly, I'm also not sure if my whole calculation is already correct. Can anyone help me with this problem? I am open to any suggestions/solutions for solving the very last integral, or even for the very first integral in the question. Any help/feedback is much appreciated. Thank you!

I'm not in any way trying to begrudge the fine work you have already done, but Feynman trick might be easier (a one liner even) if you know the second derivative of the Gamma function already. $$I = \frac{d^2}{da^2}\left[\int_0^\infty t^ae^{-t}dt\right]_{a=\frac{1}{2}} = \Gamma^{''}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$$

@NinadMunshi Hi! Thank you for the quick response. Yes, I am aware that the main integral in question is equivalent to $\Gamma''\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$. I saw some related posts that mentioned the use of the digamma function $\psi(x)$, but I am not entirely sure how to utilize it. I am, however, trying to solve this integral using some direct techniques in calculus, as I need the final result of the integral for some other part of my work. Would you please guide me through any other ideas? Thanks in advance!

$$ I = \int \log^2(t) \,\sqrt t\, e^{-t} \, dt=8\int \log ^2(x)\,x^2\,e^{-x^2} \,dx $$ can be computed in terms of hypergeometric functions but, I suppose that you are not interested by such an approach (it requires one integration by parts making the error function appearing in it).
With regard to
$$J=\frac 3 2 \int \frac{\log (y)\, \log (y+1)}{(y+1)^{5/2}}\, dy$$ l
$$y=x^2-1 \quad \implies \quad J=6 \int \frac{\log (x) \,\log \left(x^2-1\right)}{x^4}\,dx$$ One integration by parts
$$J=-\frac{2 \log (x) \log \left(x^2-1\right)}{x^3}+\int \Bigg(\frac{4 \log (x)}{x^2 \left(x^2-1\right)}+\frac{2 \log \left(x^2-1\right)}{x^4} \Bigg)\,dx$$ which is more simple. Using a few more integrations by parts
$$\int\frac{\log (x)}{x^2 \left(x^2-1\right)}\,dx=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2} \log (x+1) \log (x)+\frac{\log (x)}{x}-\frac{1}{2} (\text{Li}_2(1-x)+\text{Li}_2(-x))$$
$$\int\frac{\log \left(x^2-1\right)}{x^4} \,dx=-\frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{\log \left(x^2-1\right)}{x^3}-\frac{2}{x}+2 \tanh ^{-1}(x)\right)$$ Combining all the above and using the bounds
\begin{align*}
    \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{3 \log(y+1) \log(y)}{2(y+1)^{5/2}} \, d y=\frac{\pi ^2}2-\frac{4}{3} (4-\log (2))
\end{align*}

Hi, thank you very much for your response. I really love your answer! I am still kind of confused as to how the bounds are applied to the integral $\int \frac{\log(x)}{x^2(x^2-1)} dx$. I'm new to the dilogarithm function, and I've taken a look at it. But, I can't quite figure out how the said integral is evaluated at the integral bounds (which, in this case is 1 and $\infty$). Would you mind guiding me through the process? Thank you before!
